# Group by multiple keys and ignore case

Tags: c#, linq

When I try to do the following,

```
collection.GroupBy(item => new
                        {
                            item.Item1,
                            item.Item2,
                            item.Item3,
                            item.Item4
                        }, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

I get an error that the argument types cannot be inferred from the usage, and to try to specify the type arguments explicitly.

What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: There is no syntax or feature that accommodates this. You'll need to write a custom comparer. Good question though -- once I wish had a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests, the `StringComparer` is for comparing simple strings, not anonymous types.

From the MSDN page on [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Represents a string comparison operation that uses specific case and culture-based or ordinal comparison rules.

To compare your class, you can create your own comparer:

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
    {
        return String.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
               && String.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
               && String.Equals(x.Item3, y.Item3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
    {
        return string.Concat(obj.Item1.ToLower(),
                             obj.Item2.ToLower(),
                             obj.Item3.ToLower()).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use it in the `GroupBy`:

```
var collection = new List<SomeClass>();

// populate collection

collection.GroupBy(item => item, new CustomComparer());
```

That should work, although you may need to play around with it.

Comment: +1. One can consider using `Tuple<string,string,string>` instead of creating custom class.

Answer (score 2):

You need custom comparer, `StringComparer` can't compare anything but strings - i.e. anonymous type can't be compared with it.

Quick workaround would be to `ToUpper` strings in the key:

```
 collection.GroupBy(item => new
                    {
                        Item1 = item.Item1.ToUpper()
                        Item2 = item.Item2.ToString().ToUpper()
                    });
```

(Sample for `Item2` assume that its type is not string, so calling `ToString()` first.)